# Why does Friedman's Supersmoother predict using $X$ instead of $y$?

Tags: time-series, python, smoothing

I am working on friedman's supersmoother with python notebook: https://notebook.community/moreati/supersmoother/examples/Supersmoother.
In this example, data is generated randomly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn; seaborn.set()
from supersmoother import SuperSmoother, LinearSmoother

def make_test_set(N=200, rseed_x=None, rseed_y=None):
    """Code to generate the test set from Friedman 1984"""
    rng_x = np.random.RandomState(rseed_x)
    rng_y = np.random.RandomState(rseed_y)
    x = rng_x.rand(N)
    dy = x
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1 - x) ** 2) + dy * rng_y.randn(N)
    return x, y, dy

t, y, dy = make_test_set(rseed_x=0, rseed_y=1)
plt.errorbar(t, y, dy, fmt='o', alpha=0.3)
```

And SuperSmoother model is fitted to generated data:

```
# fit the supersmoother model
model = SuperSmoother()
model.fit(t, y, dy)
```

However, next step fitted model is used with another data and result is printed as smoothed data:

```
# find the smoothed fit to the data
tfit = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
yfit = model.predict(tfit)
```

I expected to see smoothed values as `yfit = model.predict(y)` but instead of `y`, `tfit` is provided for the `model.predict`. Can you please help me to explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you make model predictions using `y`? If you knew `y`, you wouldn't need the model.

Comment: I am trying to smooth y values, to eliminate irregularities.

Answer (score 1):

This model $\hat{y} = f(X)$ gives some *estimate* of $y$ as a function of $X$. The model infers $f$ using the the data provided to the `fit` method, including $y$. The command `model.predict(tfit)` is asking for the $\hat{y}$ for each of the $X$.